# Getting error while launching Edge browser through Selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have made sure that the version and build for getting the appropriate microsoft web driver. EdgeHTML version is 15.15063 and the webdriver I took is "Release 15063". The Edge browser gets launched and then closes. The below is the error log...

> [16:57:07.397] - Listening on http://localhost:39653/  Nov 08, 2018
>   4:57:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 0 milliseconds Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision:
>   '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z' System info: host:
>   'XXXXX', ip: '0.0.0.0', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver Capabilities {acceptSslCerts:
>   true, applicationCacheEnabled: true, browserName: MicrosoftEdge,
>   browserVersion: 40.15063.674.0, javascriptEnabled: true,
>   locationContextEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform:
>   WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10,
>   takesElementScreenshot: true, takesScreenshot: true,
>   webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID:
>   B9D4A392-E7DA-4F7B-A6EE-C3CA2A71EE82 at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions.deleteAllCookies(RemoteWebDriver.java:685)

Answer (score 0):

i Hope The Problem May be With your Browser or driver.

Please update Your Edge Browser or Take The Version from here - `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/`   Which Supports Yours.

My Edge Browser Version is :

```
Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134
```

and Am using Webdriver Version -`Release 17134`

At The First i Got Webdriver Exception, Even Though i used Correct Versions, After That i was Throwing Webdriver Exception. the Error was Cleared.

Like this:

```
    public void beforeTest() throws **WebDriverException**
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","F:\\New folder\\MicrosoftWebDriver (2).exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```